# Unable to redirect the output of a file

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect the output of:

```
 xterm -e rosrun find_object_2d print_objects_detected
```

to a location.txt file. I am doing this by using:
        `xterm -e rosrun find_object_2d print_objects_detected 2>&1 > /home/username/location.txt`. I have also tried
        `xterm -e rosrun find_object_2d print_objects_detected 2>&1 | tee -a /home/username/location.txt`. Both of these create the location.txt file but neither actually write to it. I can see the information displayed in the terminal window. Why is this and is there a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. One minute it was working, the next I cannot redirect command output to a file. Something is very wrong with n00buntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the whole command into double quotes. Without double quotes you are redirecting output of `xterm` command, which by itself doesn't do anything. In other words, you need to be specific about what you are redirecting

Demo:

```
xieerqi:$ xterm -e "printf hello world > /home/xieerqi/REDIR "

xieerqi:$ cat REDIR
hello
xieerqi:$ xterm -e printf hello world two > /home/xieerqi/REDIR   

xieerqi:$ cat REDIR

xieerqi:$
```